# How do I map a non-binary Occupancy Grid with several values to a cost map in ROS?

Tags: navigation, ros

I'm looking for a way to map a non-binary occupancy grid to a global cost map. The occupancy grid has the values -1 for undefined, 0 for non-collision and 1-100 for collision areas. There is a similar question here for which the given answer doesn't offer a concrete solution:

https://answers.ros.org/question/335530/what-range-of-costs-does-ros-navigation-support/

For a better overview:

I'm using ROS Melodic.

My occupancy grid looks like this:
[Image of Occupancy grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QEQO.png)

My global_costmap_params.yaml looks like this:

```
global_costmap:
plugins: 
- {name: static_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
- {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
global_frame: base_link
map_topic: "prediction_occ_grid"
update_frequency: 10.0
publish_frequency: 10.0
rolling_window: true
always_send_full_costmap: true
height: 26.9
width: 36.4
```

Note that I'm a pure beginner in costmaps, so it might be that this doesn't make sense at all!

Using the given global_costmap_params.yaml deliveres the following costmap: [Image of the resulting global costmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MErnf.png)

As you can see the costmap "ignores" the collision-areas and maps them in the same costs as the non-collision-path-area. Is there any way to modify the costmap_params in order for it to map the occupancy grid properly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I might be reading it wrong, but it kindof looks correct. Both costmap and occupancy_grid use cells of uint_8 values (0-255), but [costmap assumes thresholds within that for collision](https://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d#Inflation), where 1-127 is 'no collision'. I would look at the actual values of the wall-thing where the lidar marks an obstacle in the occ_grid and then at the numeric values in the costmap. Your two plugins mean to use the occ_grid, and "spread out" those values, to negatively weight nearby traversal. If you don't actually see anything (end of range), the val might be set lowly.

Comment: But doesn't the occupancy grid only take values from -1 to 100?  (According to http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html)

Comment: Oops, yeah, my bad. I was mentally thinking of both being effectively percents, where occ_grid is literally a percent, because they used a bit to signal unknown. This shouldn't change the issue though. Have you checked if the numbers, translated are equivalent, though? An update to the occ_grid that's high (eg. 100) should result in a high costmap value at that spot, if a robot polygon is specified. You may also want to read [this tutorial](https://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials/Navigation%20Tuning%20Guide) if not already.

Comment: I checked it by playing with the lethal_cost_threshold-param of the static_map. It's default is 100 and when I set that value to 50, half of the map is black, which makes sense since in my occupancy-grid, obstacle-area-values decrease from 100 to 0 with increasing distance from the origin. I tried switching the trinary_costmap-param to false (its default is true) as adviced, which - according to its description - is supposed to do exactly what I need (If false, a full spectrum of intermediate values is possible.) But somehow it still doesn't work. I think, I'm still missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out the plugin somehow isn't able to read the given params from the global_costmap_params.yaml (any ideas about what the reason could be or how to fix that?).

I solved the issue by cloning the navigation-repo into my catkin_ws/src folder (instead of installing navigation via sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-navigation) and **change the default-value** for the **trinary_costmap**-param inside costmap_2d/plugins/**static_layer.cpp** to **'false'**.

It's now able to map all intermediate values of the occupancy grid correctly.

**Edit:**

I figured out that this is due to a namespace issue. Since the *trinary_costmap* is a plugin-internal parameter for the static_layer-plugin, it appears that the namespace must be specified explicitly.

Therefore, setting the param in *global_costmap_params.yaml* like this works:

**/move_base/global_costmap/static_layer/trinary_costmap: false**

Comment: Interesting; if that's what it took to solve your prob, I'm now curious. nj

Answer (score 1):

Most specifically, I'd look at the costmap params for the plugins, chiefly the [`static_map`](https://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/staticmap) and [`obstacles`](https://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/hydro/obstacles) plugins. Perhaps you want the `staticmap` parameter `trinary_costmap` to be true, to have the full scale of values in the costmap. The ones in `obstacles` are likely to change what you expect to see, with multiple layers or input data.

I would also look at Clearpath's Husky [husky_navigation](https://github.com/husky/husky/tree/melodic-devel/husky_navigation) package for a good example, ex. [move_base.launch](https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/melodic-devel/husky_navigation/launch/move_base.launch) file. All the parameters are written in the `config/` dir, and loaded by `rosparam` within the `move_base` node. Some details: if you're doing a local costmap that moves with the robot, you don't want to track the empty space, you'd want a rolling window, and to use the Obstacle layer instead of the static layer; for the global, you would track all the space, but not move the window with respect to the robot, and you'd use a static map.

I think one issue you have is in data flow. How Ros (& most people, because of it) leans is to have an initial/static map loaded from the beginning (`map_server`) for both `amcl` and `move_base`, update both with either `LaserScan`s &/or `PointCloud`s, and then you're just left with the `amcl` output of frame tfs & local position estimation, and feeding that into the `move_base` node, you only need the `goal`. To use an occ_grid map msg to update `amcl`, for example, you have to change the `use_map_topic` param.

Edit:
In case [`map_server`](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server#Value_Interpretation) was what you really needed, here's an example usage I pulled from husky_nav's [`amcl_demo.launch`](https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/melodic-devel/husky_navigation/launch/amcl_demo.launch):

```xml
<!-- Run the map server -->
<arg name="map_file" default="$(find husky_navigation)/maps/playpen_map.yaml"/>
<node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />
```

Comment: I just had a look on husky_navigation, but it looks like there are only the default-values of the layers used. And I know that the global map actually isn't supposed to move along with the robot. In our application it is due to the fact, that we don't have a fixed area in which we move. Therefore, we use images received from a camera to detect our environment and see the path in front of us which we then pretend to be our global map. There's another problem with this which I'm going to address in another thread..

Comment: As I already mentioned, changing the trinary_costmap to false (because true is the default value and means that only 3 values, namely NO_INFORMATION, FREE_SPACE and LETHAL_OBSTACLE are considered) appears to be a good step but still the map somehow only shows those three values. I think I'll have to additionally change something else in order for the map to really use intermediate values (since the description of the trinary_costmap-param only says, that by switching to false, intermediate values are possible which doesn't mean that they are actually used by doing so)

Comment: I also had a look at the map_server-description ([link]http://wiki.ros.org/map_server#Value_Interpretation). In the section Value_Interpretation it says that the interpretation-type "Scale" should do exactly what I need! Do you know where to set the params of map_server?

Comment: map_server publishes a static map, loaded from file once, and will keep providing it on a service request. As you say, it _does_ have a weird non-standard parameter input: giving the map config yaml file as a cmd line arg. For ex, referring back to the husky_nav pkg, the [`amcl_demo.launch`](https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/melodic-devel/husky_navigation/launch/amcl_demo.launch) file has an example usage of `map_server`. I've updated my answer with that.

Comment: (Interesting sounding project. You might find [rtabmap](https://introlab.github.io/rtabmap/) [ros](https://wiki.ros.org/rtabmap_ros) interesting as a one-stop solution to nav, should your camera have depth or reconstruction). Also, you can have a giant global map, and then do map management to break it smaller, but it might help not to pre-maturely optimize away from a simple static global map and rolling local map until those are working.

Comment: It looks like map_server only translates an image to an occupancy grid but does not offer a costmap. It looks like costmap_2d really only is able to provide three or four values: FREE_SPACE=0, INSCRIBED_INFLATED_OBSTACLE=253, LETHAL_OBSTACLE=254 and NO_INFORMATION=255 (see http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/costmap_2d/html/namespacecostmap__2d.html). Could it be that the only way to solve this is writing a custom layer (see http://wiki.ros.org/costmap_2d/Tutorials/Creating%20a%20New%20Layer) that simply maps the occupancy-grid values (range -1 to 100) to costmap values (range 0-255)?

Comment: `map_server` has 3 `mode`s, as a parameter (on the ros.wiki page): trinary, scale, and raw, the last of which will use the raw [0,255] values. `map_server`, for convenience, since it's usually used to load static maps (not of obstacles, but infrastructure) offers to pre-process the map to a few max/min values. If this is still confusing/wrong, could you update with some numerical examples of what the occ_grid is at the boundary & what the costmap values are at the same boundary?

Comment: But as far as I understood, since I need a costmap, map_server won't help at that point. Do you know how I could get the value of a specific point of the costmap in order to compare it with the value of the occgrid?